# Spring Boot, Can't access h2-console when integrated with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, h2, h2-console

I'm writing a Spring-Boot project that uses `Spring Security`, and also I want to use the `H2` database.

I've got a problem when I access `localhost:8080/h2-console`, it keeps returning `403` (as I understand, it's from the `Spring Security` and I need to let it ignore the `H2` endpoint (`/h2-console/**`) for authentication).

Here is my configuration class, I'm using this but it still returns `403`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFiler;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //Spring will create new session foreach request
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFiler, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

More details:

- I'm using `Spring Boot 3.0.6`
- I'm using `HttpSecurity` class from `package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders;` , version `61.0` (Java17)

Is anyone facing this, please help to suggest the proper solution.

Comment: But you also have to disable your custom filter for the request as Veera Raghava Sai varma wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your h2-cnsole there once while attempting to keep the web security config. I believe that Spring Security has to be enabled in order to provide the security required to permit unauthenticated access. Take off the request matcher from the security filter chain and try passing via a different function. Only for that h2console.

Comment: Umm. I've tried to split it out to another function (another Bean) but it still returns 403.

Comment: Okay, give the antMatchers a try. They can help you bring the paths up against a specified pattern, which might be of help.